# Attr_reader for Active Record model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actiondispatch

```
Article.rb < ActiveRecord::Base   
... 

attr_reader :title

def title
    self.title.gsub(/"/," ")
end

end
```

I am trying to overwrite the way each articles title is displayed because it looks ugly if I don't but I keep getting an error like so:

```
SystemStackError in ArticlesController#index or StackLevelTooDeep
```

I am not sure how to remedy this problem. If I change the method to something different like ntitle, it will work. WHY?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you call `self.title` inside `def title` it call itself, so you get infinite recursion, and it cause error `StackLevelTooDeep`.

This should work:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def title
    read_attribute(:title).to_s.gsub(?", " ")
  end

end
```

Comment: thanks so much. Can't believe I was calling it inside itself. much appreciated